# Unittesting in Vala

Tags: unit-testing, glib, vala

I've now written a few unittests using GLibs inbuilt unit tests, in Vala. That means everything is done as:

```
class test_some_class{

    static void main(string[] args){

        Test.ref(args);

        Test.add_func("/some/path/test-some-functionality", test_some_functionality);

        Test.run();

    }

    static void test_some_functionality() {

        assert(true); //Or any other boolean expression such as 'a == b' as pointed out by @AlexB 

    }
}
```

There's nothing on valadoc specifying available functions to compare strings, doubles, etc.

While unittesting in general is tedious (but necessary) I find it particularly tedious here, these seems to be rather barebones unittests, missing much that is offered in JUnit and mstests (for .NET Core). I was wondering if someone can recommend a good unittesting framework written for/with GLib Tests, that offers something similar?

I have looked at valadate, but it does not seem to get a lot of attention these days, and while it may not need frequent updates, I have been quite unable to locate working samples, and the wiki does too seem to be offline. If anyone is currently using it, please speakup, and please do show some examples.

In particular it would be nice to be able to merely create the classes, declare the functions with decorations that specify them as tests that should be run.

Comment: well you can do assert (a == b) of course, see [Vala/TestSample](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/TestSample)

Comment: @AlexB Yes. it takes a boolean expression. be it 'true' or 'a == b' or 'a > b' etc. That is pretty much what I am doing, but it's just that this way of writing unit tests, seem to involve a lot of redundant boilerplate code. And I am VERY interested in reducing the amount of time i spend doing that. And i Could probably design an abstract class that will handle a lot of this for me, and then just inherit that everywhere. But I'd rather use something developed and maintained by someone else. I already have a lot on my plate :)

Comment: tbh pretty much any testing framework you use will be quite verbose and GLib.Test is pretty much you only option for Vala. In future we may get things like [µtest](https://github.com/ebassi/mutest) but that's experimental for now (and doesn't have a vapi)

Comment: I gave it some thought, and ended up creating a few classes, that makes for a bit less boilerplate. It's nothing special, but I will post the solution here later, in case anyone else finds themselves in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, there's no great solution in the standard library unfortunately, especially since many of GLib's `g_assert_foo` methods don't work or don't make sense under Vala.

For Geary, I've adopted [this approach](https://esite.ch/2012/06/writing-tests-for-vala/) that uses a class-based framework similar to JUnit and integrates into the existing GLib test harness, but modified it to throw errors rather than use plain `assert()` calls, and added support for mock objects, a wider range of `assert_foo` methods, handle expected/unexpected errors and testing async methods. See the [test directory](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/geary/tree/mainline/test) in Geary's source, in particular the files `test-case.vala` and `mock-object.vala`.

It could certainly use a lot of cleanup, but is independent of Geary's application code, and so could easily be imported and used elsewhere. I'd be happy to split it out into a separate library if anyone is interested in using and contributing back to it.

Comment: Thanks. That first link of yours, I have looked at before, but I was unable to make it work.

Comment: Do you reference a particular library to use these, or do you just copy a few classes?

Comment: Just copied the TestCase class source from that blog post with attribution (actually the version by Julien Peeters they link to), hooked it up to the build, and started adding test cases. It's a good starting point, but is missing a bunch of useful features you'd need to add yourself - that's how Geary's version of same (in `test-case.vala`) came to to be how it is.

Comment: I'm likely to copy the Geary version then. Do I need to add any additional information in the attributions? :) Will accept answer when I've tried using this

Comment: Well per the file itself, the code is licenced LGPL 2.1, so if you redistribute it you'd need to ensure that's compatible with the licence your project uses. That aside if you'd retain the two copyright lines as long as there's code from either Geary's or the the original version, then you should be good to go. That would keep me happy at least. :)